# Flutter: `notifyListeners` not updating the list

Tags: list, flutter, provider

I am trying to list categories of products in my app, and i am using provider package for state management. During the build time its shows the list is empty even though it is not, then I add a click event to update the list that time it works.
I call the `getAllCategories()` function during the splash screen and the `vallCategoryList` has values.

This is my category class

```
class Category with ChangeNotifier{

  int catId;
  String catName;
  String catThumbnail;

  List<SetCategory> allCategoryList = [];


void  getAllCategories() async {
    String categoryUrl = 'https://app.ecwid.com/api/ccccccc';

    Response allCategory = await get(categoryUrl);

    print('getAllCategories');


    if (allCategory.statusCode == 200) {
      var categoryData = allCategory.body;

      int totalcount = jsonDecode(categoryData)['count'];

      if (allCategoryList.length != totalcount) {
        allCategoryList.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalcount; i++) {
          allCategoryList.add(SetCategory(
            catId: jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['id'],
            catName: jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['name'],
            catThumbnail: jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['thumbnailUrl'],
          ));

        }

      }
    }
    print('allcategorylist length ${allCategoryList.length}');

    notifyListeners();
  }



}

class SetCategory {

  int catId;
  String catName;
  String catThumbnail;

  SetCategory(
      { this.catId, this.catName, this.catThumbnail});

}
```

My code for screen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'homeScreen';
//  static int reload = 0;



  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      final category = Provider.of<Category>(context);

    print('category length ${category.allCategoryList.length}'); // here it shows length as 0 even though it has a value of 16.

    return Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Category ${category.allCategoryList.length}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),

                  InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {

                                        category.getAllCategories();  // when i tap here this updates the list
                                        }),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `ChangeNotifierProvider` in your Widget as shown [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider)

If you just used `Provider` it is not updating but just makes the object accessible from the descendants

Comment: Yes i added it in the main.dart file like this `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Category>(
      builder: (context)=>Category(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: customsplash.SplashScreen.id,
        routes: {
          customsplash.SplashScreen.id: (context)=>customsplash.SplashScreen(),
          HomeScreen.id: (context)=>HomeScreen(),
    },),);`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding a `Consumer`, changed code like this

```
child: Consumer<Category>(
                        builder: (_,category,__){
                          return ListView.builder();
}
```